# Add fixed spacing between two internal elements of a list

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I am working on building a basic to-do list.

I have a list of elements with delete option for each element next to it.

I am facing issues with having proper spacing between the list elements namely "to-do text" and "Delete" icon.

Note: I'm new to Web programming.

Comment: "*I am facing issues with having proper spacing*" It's not at all clear what "*proper spacing*" means in this specific context, as you haven't provided your *expected* output of this code (nor have you stated what *specifically* you've tried in order to resolve it before posting here). Please review [ask] and edit your question to conform to the guidance therein.

Answer (score -1):

You could set a fixed width on the container element and then use flex box:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: flex;
                background-color: grey;
                border: 1px solid darkGrey;
                width: 300px;
                padding: 10px 15px;
            }
            .title {
                flex: 1;
                padding-right: 3px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">sample text</div>
            <div>delete icon</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">long sample text for illustration purposes.</div>
            <div>delete icon</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```